# c++ multithreaded file read on windows

Tags: multithreading

I'm looking for a clean way to load a file from disk to memory on windows using multiple threads in parallel. I intend to use this with pci-e based SSD disks, which allow parallel reads/writes.

Comment: Could you just set each thread to seek to a position based on their thread id and the number of threads you're using and just have it read bytes/n? You'd need multiple ifstream instances, one for each thread.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/

Comment: Or just memory-map the file and leave it to the OS.